# How can i clone record use deepclone() method and update clone recorded id with its related list?

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, clone, list-button

The problem arising clone recorded id does'not updated so and does'not appear related list and updated field so how should i do this?

**Apex class**

```
Public Class CloneVersionwithTextController{

Public List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist{get;set;}
Public Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy;
public string msaid{get;set;}

Public CloneVersionwithTextController(){

    msaid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('msaid');    

}  
public void cloneRec(){
    system.debug('===clonme()===='+msaid );
    List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist = new List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c>();
    msalist = [SELECT  Name, Status__c FROM Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c WHERE Id = : msaid ];
    if(msaList.size() > 0){
        msaList.get(0).Name = msaList.get(0).Name + '    ' + Datetime.now();
    }
    Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msalist[0].clone(false,true); 
    insert msaCopy;
    List<MSA_Text_Block__c> mtext = new List<MSA_Text_Block__c>();
    system.debug('===mtext===='+mtext);
    mtext = [SELECT Id, Name, Service__c, Order_within_Service__c,Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID,LastModifiedBy.Name FROM MSA_Text_Block__c WHERE Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID = : msaid];
    for(MSA_Text_Block__c c : mtext)
    {
        MSA_Text_Block__c mtextCopy = c.clone(false,true);
        mtextCopy.Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c = msaCopy.Id;
        mtext.add(mtextCopy);
    }
    system.debug('===msaList===='+msaList);*/

}
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="CloneVersionwithTextController" action="{!cloneRec}">
   <apex:detail subject="{!msaid}" relatedList="true" title="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you try clone(true,true,false,true)

Comment: sam i clone the record show that error 
Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3MP0000000CdtiMAC; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]
Error is in expression '{!cloneRec}' in component <apex:page> in page cloneversionwithtext: Class.CloneVersionwithTextController.cloneRec: line 20, column 1

Comment: Clone(true,true,false,true) is trying to retain ID of current record so you have to use upsert.

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to update the record. Change the statement to:

```
    Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msalist[0].clone(true,true,false,false); 
    update msaCopy;
```

or every place where you want update record. To update record Id is required.

If you want to insert record then clone would be like:

```
        // Don't retain ID
        Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msalist[0].clone(false,true,false,false); 
        update msaCopy;
```